# Compiling tikzmanual example with chains and branches

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

Does someone know how I must compile the example of the tikz/pgf user manual (v2.10) in section 28.5:

```
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every on chain/.style=join,every join/.style=->,
node distance=2mm and 1cm]
{ [start chain=trunk]
\node [on chain] {A};
\node [on chain] {B};
{ [start branch=numbers going below]
\node [on chain] {1};
\node [on chain] {2};
\node [on chain] {3};
}
{ [start branch=greek going above]
\node [on chain] {$\alpha$};
\node [on chain] {$\beta$};
\node [on chain] {$\gamma$};
}
\node [on chain,join=with trunk/numbers-end,join=with trunk/greek-end] {C};
{ [start branch=symbols going below]
\node [on chain] {$\star$};
\node [on chain] {$\circ$};
\node [on chain] {$\int$};
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Like this I get

```
Line 6: Package tikz Error: Unknown chain ``chain''.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. Can you please complete your MWE so it is running? (`\documentclass...` til `\end{document}`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Load the `scopes` library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every on chain/.style=join,every join/.style=->,
node distance=2mm and 1cm]
{ [start chain=trunk]
\node [on chain] {A};
\node [on chain] {B};
{ [start branch=numbers going below]
\node [on chain] {1};
\node [on chain] {2};
\node [on chain] {3};
}
{ [start branch=greek going above]
\node [on chain] {$\alpha$};
\node [on chain] {$\beta$};
\node [on chain] {$\gamma$};
}
\node [on chain,join=with trunk/numbers-end,join=with trunk/greek-end] {C};
{ [start branch=symbols going below]
\node [on chain] {$\star$};
\node [on chain] {$\circ$};
\node [on chain] {$\int$};
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The presence of an opening brace followed by some options (inside square brackets) usually indicates the syntax for a scope provided by the `scopes` library.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere reasonably findable? The `tikz` manual has the frustrating habit of almost never including **complete** examples. Given the size of the manual, this makes it extremely difficult to learn. The expectation seems to be that you'll somehow intuit the necessary additions. Even knowing I want the `scopes` library, I can't find anything about it ;). The only entry in the index points to page 128 which is about `quotes` not `scopes`!

Comment: @cfr Section **12.3.2 Shorthand for Scope Environments** (page 128) of the manual for version 3.0.0.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea why the link from the index took me to `quotes` before.